# css text-align does not work unless in both local style and external stylesheet? Whats going on?

Tags: css, text-align

I have a css class .menu-bar.

```
<style>
    .menu-bar { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
</style>
```

If I place the class in external stylesheet, it won't load ( has no effect in html file ).
If I place the class in local stylesheet (in head tag), it only works if the class is also defined in the external stylesheet. I know this, because I removed the class from external stylesheet and the local class did nothing. My observations have been, this is being caused by text-align. What is going on?

My implementing code:

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div> Content </div>
</div>
```

My intention is to place my css code in external stylesheets. In this scenario, I am having to duplicate this code which seems to demean the point of having external stylesheets. Any thoughts would helpful.

Comment: Could it be some mistake in your code? Probably a missing semicolon or an extra curly bracket, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally Use **VS code** as far I can see your problem is that you are not able to link your external stylesheet (CSS file) If You use vs code you can use this.

Maybe some problem in the live server or anything if the code doesn't work the problem maybe something else.

Correct me if I am wrong!

**MY CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="menu-bar">
           <div>
               <p>Content *Text align - center Text horizontally*. </p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE (External Sheet)**

```
.menu-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

[Click me to view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFxCc.png)

Comment: This seems to be the closest tip/answer. It turns out it may have been an inability to link the external stylesheet.  I forgot to remove the style tag from the external sheet. Seems to work now. I also added type="text/css" to each of the link tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The external CSS code did not run because you did not import it in your HTML.
Add this to the start of your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PATH_TO_CSS.css">
```